# Why Typescript throw error message: Property does not exist on type?

Tags: typescript, redux

I created two code examples. The only difference between them is what expression I pass to the switch operator.

In a first case I use an object property. And it works fine.

In a second case I create a `type` variable. And Typescript throw an error message:

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Action'.
>
> Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ type: "reset"; }'.

Why is this happening?

The object property `action.type` and variable `type` are of the same type `'reset' | 'update'` .

```js
interface State {
    name: string;
    cars: any[];
}

type Action = { type: 'reset' } | { type: 'update', name: string };

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'update':
            return { ...state, name: action.name };
        case 'reset':
            return {...state, cars: [] };
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
}
```

```js
interface State {
    name: string;
    cars: any[];
}

type Action = { type: 'reset' } | { type: 'update', name: string };

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
    /**
    * Create a 'type' variable
    */
    const { type } = action;

    switch (type) {
        case 'update':
            return { ...state, name: action.name };
    /**
    * Typescript will throw an error message
    * Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Action'.
    * Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ type: "reset"; }'.
    */
        case 'reset':
            return {...state, cars: [] };
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
}
```

[Image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BHPF.png)

Comment: type Action = { type: 'reset' } | { type: 'update', name: string };

You have to set a value for name property here instead name: string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, Typescript doesn't keep track of a relationship between the types of the variables `action` and `type`; when `type`'s type is narrowed (such as in a `case` of a `switch` statement), it doesn't also narrow `action`'s type.

On the assignment `const { type } = action;`, the compiler infers `type: Action['type']`, which happens to be `'reset' | 'update'`. Later, the `case` expression doesn't narrow the type of `action` because no type-guarding check was done on `action`.

For this to behave the way you want it to behave, the compiler would have to introduce a type variable `T extends Action['type']` and infer `type: T`, while simultaneously narrowing `action` to the type `: Action & { type: T }`. Then when `type`'s type is narrowed, `T` itself would have to be narrowed, so the effect would propagate to `action`'s type which would involve `T`.

Introducing a new type variable like this on every variable assignment, and control-flow narrowing the upper bounds of type variables, would greatly complicate the type-checking algorithm. It would also greatly complicate the inferred types making them harder for users to understand; so it's reasonable that Typescript doesn't do this. Generally speaking, type-checkers don't prove every provable property of your code, and this is an example.

Answer (score 1):

When you refer to the argument it can infer the type from the whole object but when you create a constant you limit the type to simply become `"reset" | "update"` and the other bits of Action object type info is lost.