# Typescript guard fails on union types

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why TypeScript complains about a possible undefined object (`customer.id`) in this example:

```js
type Customer = {
  id: string
  company: string
}

type Props =
  | {
      mode: 'new'
      customer: undefined
    }
  | {
      mode: 'edit'
      customer: Customer
  }

function form({ mode, customer }: Props) {
  const formId = mode === 'edit' ? customer.id : 'foo'
}
```

From my understand, customer can never be `undefined` as lang as `mode` is `edit`. I thought that this one is some sort of TypeScript Guard?

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYQE5QLxQN4BQUUAlgCYBcUSGJAdgOZFQDGaYAhnSFTfUwF8CBUJCgAFDMjAIczAD75mxYqmRkIVAOR0IAdy3KVLRCnQYqcOhoBm9CGSNDiiwipVqN2hyWCH3xCZIaJhU8MHmzEIENlYswCTIdFA2yBioABR4UJ4QADSspiFYAlSS0ggAlEqBSUgpaagAkmQ4OerQ2F1QWj5+UAD8hRGYAHTkUNqpyIYCQA)

Comment: Do it without destructuring - `obj.mode === 'edit' ? obj.customer.id : 'foo'`. Typescript cannot do control-flow type narrowing in a way that remembers a relationship between two different variables.

Comment: This answer explains why using two separate variables doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58861215/12299000