# Why discriminated union typescript doesn't work?

Tags: typescript

I have these types

```js
type TARGET_EDIT_SKILL = {
  section: 'skills';
  property: 'type';
  index: number;
  foobar: string;
};

type TARGET_EDIT_EXPERIENCE = {
  section: 'experience';
  property: 'time' | 'position' | 'name' | 'summary';
  index: number;
};

type ACTION_EDIT_SECTION = {
  type: typeof EDIT_SECTION;
  payload: {
    target: TARGET_EDIT_SKILL | TARGET_EDIT_EXPERIENCE;
    value: string;
  };
};

export type Actions =
  | ACTION_UPDATE_DATA
  | ACTION_EDIT_TITLE
  | ACTION_EDIT_SKILL
  | ACTION_EDIT_SECTION;
```

And then in reducer

```js
case actions.EDIT_SECTION: {
      const { target, value } = action.payload;
      const { section, property, index } = target;

      if (section === 'skills') {
        console.log(target.foobar);
        return property === 'time';
      }

      ...
    }
```

But I got typescript error "Property 'foobar' does not exist on type 'TARGET_EDIT_EDUCATION'". Why? I thought if I narrow type with section condition then foobar must exist. And why `return property === 'time';` isn't type `never`? `time` never exists on type with section "skills".

-- EDIT

One more thing, I have

```
const newSetion = [...state[target.section]];
// const newSection: (Skill | Education | Experience | Language)[]
```

```
newSection[0][target.property] = value;
```

Why it says `Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Skill | Experience | Education | Language'.` if it already knows that `newSection` is `state.skills` and property `type` exists there.

Comment: Does it changes if you put as `target.section === "skills"`?

Comment: Please provide reproducable example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Typescript throw error message: Property does not exist on type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860893/why-typescript-throw-error-message-property-does-not-exist-on-type)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Make sure it is complete and all related types like `Skill` and others are mentioned. Also, please focus only one problem in one question.

Answer (score 3):

You've split the object apart into independant local variables, so there's no longer a link between the types. Checking the type on the local variable `section` has no impact on the type of `target`. You and i may be able to see the relationship, but typescript doesn't have the ability to back track to figure out how the types originated and then calculate all the consequences to other variables

To narrow the type of `target` you need to check a property on `target`, as in:

```
if (target.section === 'skills') {
  // now the type on target has been narrowed
  console.log(target.foobar)
}
```

Though i believe you'll run into a further problem that `section` doesn't appear on all the possible types in your union, so typescript won't let you access `target.section`. So for that you'll need:

```
if ('section' in target && target.section === 'skills) {
```

Comment: Please check out Edit

Comment: @MateuszPiguła Please focus only one problem/error in one question.